# How to add a video timeline in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So i was using Rythm bot in discord and while using the command `{prefix}np` i noticed that there is video duration display. Please view the given image.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNnRa.png)

I wanna know how to do it in `discord.py`, it might be useful for me. When you seek a specific time frame, it should display the timeline with correct ratio and proportion(i exactly don't know how to explain it but you get it right). I tried doing myself and i failed. so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to determine the `length of the song`, the `current play length`, and `how many characters` long your answer should be.

Now you have to `determine the location of the play sign` (current_length).
You can do that by `doing the same as if you wanted to calculate a percentage`, but instead of 100% maximum you want the character length (20 in this case) as maximum:

```
current_length = display_length / total_seconds * current_seconds
```

You also have to convert `current_length` to an `integer` so you can determine its loaction in the `display_string`

So, putting that into code:

```
total_seconds = 217
current_seconds = 132

display_string = ""
display_length = 20

current_length = int(display_length / total_seconds * current_seconds)

for i in range(display_length):
    if i == current_length:
        display_string += ">"
    else:
        display_string += "-"

print(display_string)
```